# Is it good practice to write Intent dispatching as static methods in the class to be launched?

Tags: android, android-intent, coding-style

I'm just starting Android development, so I'd like a little advice on code style. It seems nice to me to write `Intent` dispatchers in methods that are doing the dispatching, like

```
// in case it's not clear, names are meta-variables

public class MyService...
    ...

    public static void sendMessage(Context ctx, MyArgClass myArg) {
        Intent sendIntent = new Intent(ctx, MyService.class);
        sendIntent.setAction("send message");
        sendIntent.putExtra("my_arg", myArg);
        ctx.startService(sendIntent);
    }
}
```

then, any callees just run `MyService.sendMessage(ctx, arg)`, instead of having the `Intent` creation code in their bodies.

It seems like a win: there's less stuff to remember when you want to e.g. `sendMessage`, and you don't have to synchronize names, like `"send message"` and `"my_arg"` across modules. However, I don't see it that often in Google's music app that they've open sourced, so I'm wondering if there are downsides, and I should stick to convention.

Comment: Nothing bad with that, you can even set "send message" as parameter, to make it even more generic.

Comment: @wingman, actually, the idea was to intercept the "send message" string with a "case" statement in `onStartCommand`, i.e. it's a token that's internal to MyService, designating that a request came from the `sendMessage()` entry point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is good practice. This pattern can be found in android developer guides ([sample](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html#BasicDialog))

Answer (score 1):

Please allow me to answer your question in a more general context, ie programming approach static vs singletin, since these are the alternatives I would consider.

I found that using static solutions for global access to methods, constants, etc.. seems to be a matter of taste.

One commonly used alternative is a singeton approach where you create only one instance of an obejct and use this to access your method. So also in your case you could use a sigleton instead - I have not looked at the Google code you referring to, but I wouldn't be surprised to see a singelton pattern instead.

You may find several discussions on that - but in general singletons allow you to reuse code and control object state much easier than static. The main difference is that singletons can implement interfaces, so you can pass them around.

However, in cases where I just need easy access to some utility methods I prefer static solutions - since they are easier and faster to implement and use IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

This is like having a Utility method to take care of this.

In the example code for `GCM` from Android, they have done a similar thing.